# C++ XML library for use under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, xml

Under Windows to parse XML one can use the COM based XML API but I wondered if there is any C++ XML libraries out there I can use for this purpose, without needing to get into the intricacies of COM?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/). Pugixml is `Light-weight, simple and fast XML parser for C++ with XPath support`

Here is the [quick start guide](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/quickstart.html), and here is a [benchmark](http://pugixml.org/benchmark/), notice how only [AsmXML](http://tibleiz.net/asm-xml/) is faster than pugixml.

Comment: That might be true. I've glanced a bit over vtd-xml and I've found that the license is GPL and funnily enough the C++ namespace is named *com_ximpleware*. pugixml (note the i from the name) is small, easy to use, well documented, fast and is written in ... C++ (I know that vtd-xml has a C++ implementation, but the level of C++ness is not the same)!

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course.

If you don't need validation, I'd suggest [TinyXML++](http://code.google.com/p/ticpp/) which is also very simple to use :

```
    ticpp::Document doc(pcFilename);
    doc.LoadFile();

    // parse through all elements
    std::string strName;
    std::string strValue;
    ticpp::Iterator<ticpp::Element> child;
    for(child = child.begin(doc.FirstChildElement()); child != child.end(); child++)
    {
            // parse through all the attributes of this fruit
            ticpp::Iterator< ticpp::Attribute > attribute;
            for(attribute = attribute.begin(child.Get()); attribute != attribute.end(); attribute++)
            {
                    attribute->GetName(&strName);
                    attribute->GetValue(&strValue);
                    std::cout << strName << ": " << strValue << std::endl;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

If you need validation, consider using [XercesC++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the most efficient open-source parser library for C, C#, C++, and Java nowadays is [VTD-XML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vtd-xml/). In terms of performance, it beats DOM, SAX, and XPath. I has converted the library to Delphi for my private project, and I found that VTD-XML is just like what it claims. See [VTD-XML Benchmark](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/benchmark1.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've used [XercesC++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) in the past to good effect.  I recently used MSXML which was all pain in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/index.html) and [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) (both C libraries) from within C++. Both do their job well, but if I was to rewrite my code again I'd probably use [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/). Xerces IMO is too large and overwhelming for my needs, while expat is too low-level. My understanding is that libxml2 is a good higher level library. (I've used the lxml python bindings for libxml2 extensively - and they work beautifully.).

Oh and I've used tinyxml a bit too (several years ago), but found its DOM model too slow for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

The Expat XML Parser is also a good one. I think you will find a C++ wapper for it somewhere.
http://expat.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search found me quite a few XML parsers for C++ other than Xerces (the most commonly used one).

I don't know how good they are. Here are two:

[libXML](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/html/)

[TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The **boost.property_tree** has the XML parser (based on RapidXml).

It's header-only and has no dependencies other than Boost.